# WINAPI: Colored Border for Static Dialog Item

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a dialog box in win32 api. I have a Static Element which has been created as below.

```
lpw = lpwAlign(lpw);     // Align DLGITEMTEMPLATE on DWORD boundary
lpdit = (LPDLGITEMTEMPLATE)lpw;
lpdit->x  = 12;
lpdit->y  = 36;
lpdit->cx = 75;
lpdit->cy = 7;
lpdit->id = ID_ERROR_MSG;
lpdit->style =  WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP | WS_VISIBLE  ;

lpw = (LPWORD)(lpdit + 1);
*lpw++ = 0xFFFF;
*lpw++ = 0x0082;        // Static class

lpwsz = (LPWSTR)lpw;
nchar = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, errorMsg.c_str(), -1, lpwsz, 50);
lpw += nchar;
*lpw++ = 0;
```

In the dialog proc I handle it using WM_PAINT With following Code.

```
HWND ErrorMessage = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, ID_ERROR_MSG);
```

and

```
hdc = BeginPaint(ErrorMessage, &ps_Confirm);
    hFont = CreateFont(18,0,0,0,FW_BOLD,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("Arial"));
        SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

        wchar_t sCaption[100];
        GetWindowText(ErrorMessage,sCaption, 100);

        //Sets the coordinates for the rectangle in which the text is to be formatted.
        SetRect(&rect, 0,0,75,7);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,0));
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));
        //SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        DrawText(hdc, sCaption, -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);
        DeleteObject(hFont);
    EndPaint(ErrorMessage, &ps_Confirm);
```

I want to have red border drawn around it. I tried using DrawEdge() but the edge is only of black color. Also, It is a bit in 3D effect. I wanted to do something like :

[image: red border]

One hack I can do is to draw a blank static with dark red color and then another static element with white color over it. But it is not a very good solution.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Wait, why are you manually drawing your static control without owner draw? And you tried `DrawEdge()` but not `Rectangle()`?

Comment: Hey, I wasn't aware of the `Rectangle()` function. However, in the suggested answer, `FrameRect()` works fine for me.

Comment: `Rectangle()` and `FrameRect()` are similar, but `FrameRect()` and `DrawEdge()` are different. For the record, `DrawEdge()` is primarily intended for drawing UI controls when themes are not in use, alongside `DrawFrameControl()`, `DrawFocusRect()`, and `DrawCaption()` (and I think `DrawState()` too but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Thanks, I will keep these in mind. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'd go about this is to *subclass* the static control. Doing so means you only need to concentrate on implementing the different behaviour that you want, rather than the entirety of a control's behaviour/logic.

First, you need to tell windows that you're doing it. Next you need to implement a WndProc (actually a SUBCLASSPROC) function for the window. Finally, you need to do the painting.

[image]

Here's a rough example:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501  // min version for subclassing funcs
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

const int errorPanelSubclassId = 1;

LRESULT paintErrorPanel(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    RECT mRect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &mRect);

    HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255,0,0) );
    FrameRect(hdc, &mRect, redBrush);
    DeleteObject(redBrush);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK subclassedWinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_PAINT)
    {
        paintErrorPanel(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    }

    else
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND errorPanel = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_ERROR_STATIC);
            SetWindowSubclass(errorPanel, subclassedWinProc, errorPanelSubclassId, NULL);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(errorPanel, subclassedWinProc, errorPanelSubclassId);
        }
        return 0;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}



int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Comment: +1, but you forgot to call [`RemoveWindowSubclass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the `WM_DESTROY` handler of the dialog box ( or you can do it in subclass procedure, in response to `WM_NCDESTROY` )... Best regards ( it has been a very long time since we "spoke" ).

Comment: Cheers, funny you should mention that - I was just thinking the same thing only a few minutes ago. I shall fix that. How'd you go with the cursors, any good? It has indeed been a while, hope you're well. :)

Comment: I am bumping on so many "interesting" problems but can not manage to solve them on my own. The biggest one is rearrangable listview. I thought of using OLE drag and drop to rearrange items but found a simpler solution. Still, I need to handle the case with multiple selection. DateTimePicker control with custom background is also an unsolvable problem. If you want, I can link here those questions or send you a comment at CP, so you can have a look... *It has indeed been a while, hope you're well. :)* Still "kicking" :) how is life treating you?

Comment: :) Sounds familiar. Oh good, it's like rock-climbing - can't go this way? Find another.. I'll take a look at the Qs you've got going. I can see them in your profile, no need to link. :) Pretty okay - recently been RC flying for the first time in about 3 years - I so needed that!

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks a lot. This was awesome. It did workout. However, I didn't need to implement SUBCLASSPROC. In the WM_PAINT message, for the dialogproc, I used FrameRect and it worked. Was there specific need to implement SUBCLASSPROC?

Comment: You're welcome. An advantage of subclassing is that the logic for the control can be contained within a single WndProc. If you're painting the control from within the WM_PAINT message handler of the dialog, you've just introduced coupling between the dialog and the control. This makes it both (a) harder to maintain and (b) less re-usable. You could, for instance, implement message handlers that would allow setting of (i) the text (already done by the static control) (ii) the border colour and (iii) the icon. This would make the subclassed control _much, much_ more flexible and re-usable. :)

Comment: @TusharGoyal - forgot to ping you with an @ symbol. I can't remember if you'd be notified anyway. Just in case you didn't get a notification, this should do it. :)

Comment: @enhzflep I agree with the concept of re usability and flexibility. This would make code less cluttered. ;) Anyways, thanks a ton.

Comment: Very nice solution, works like a charm. However, static color is being changed for some reason...